# Existing question does not cover recent versions: Extend or create new question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I need a page explaining to my customers how to check whether their Windows (any version) is 32bit or 64bit.

All I have found is [How can I find out whether my Windows is 32bit or 64 bit?](https://superuser.com/questions/36088/how-can-i-find-out-whether-my-windows-is-32bit-or-64-bit) which unfortunately says "*specifically XP and Vista*", so no answer talk about Windows 8 and Windows 10 (even though the procedure is different).

Should I create another question (with community wiki answer) about *ALL* Windows versions?
Or should I edit the question above to include later versions of Windows, and append the Windows 8 and Windows 10 ways to the top answer?

Rather than having a separate question for each version of Windows, I hope we can have a single QA explaining the procedure for all Windows versions, that would be much more worthwhile linking to, and such a page would probably be very popular.

Comment: The vista method works until 10. Feels like a *minor* edit would work here...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: The Vista method talks about a "*Programs list*", which does not exist in Windows 8.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/36100/10165 still works identically. I donno. Still seems redundant

Comment: It mentions going to control panel and selecting "system" which is correct, I think the the "programs list" is just a terminology difference saying to use the list view for the control panel rather than the confusing grouped view. An edit stating how to get to the "old" control panel and then to the System panel in Win10 would probably suffice. All the details *are* in the same place.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: It seems that most recent laptops don't have a Break key, so I am reluctant to point my customers to that solution.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - Yes it does....

Answer (score 1):

It's still the same question IMO.  The Op asks about "Windows" in general, and then specifies that, in their case, XP and Vista interest *them*.

Since answers (and questions) are not actually intended to be just for the OP, these answers can easily be expanded/updated without invalidating the question as it currently stands.

I'd suggest putting a bounty on the existing question stating that you would like updated answers that cover Windows 8 and 10.

Comment: Would it be OK to remove the "(specifically XP and Vista)" part of the question and expand the top answer to be usable with all recent versions of Windows too? I know changing the terms of the question is not something to do lightly, but in this case I believe it would make the question much more linkable to.

Comment: I believe the "*Additionally, how can I find out if my hardware will support a 64 bit operating system?*" part could also be removed, as it is a separate question and only 1 of the 6 answers addresses it.